# How can I declare current_date as variable in global code (Code Workbook)

Tags: sql, global-variables, foundry-code-workbooks

I try to declare a `current_date()` variable in the global code.

[image]

After this I try to reference this column with SQL:
`where column = aktueller_tag`

Comment: Hi mi_mir your question is very hard to understand could you perhaps edit it and make it clearer around what you are doing, what is not working and what you want to achieve?

Comment: I try to have a global variable with the current_date() where I always can reference on.

Comment: Guten tag @mi_mlr  I see that you are a new contributor. Can you please frame the question as a minimum verifiable working example? I'll do my best to answer given the information you provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guten tag mi_mlr, I see that you are a new contributor. Can you please frame the question as a [minimum verifiable working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?  I'll do my best to answer given the information you provided:

Once you get the global variable using the `current_date()`, you can reference this within any node/dataset in Code Workbooks.

This is what is in my global code:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
aktueller_tag = F.current_date()
```

Then from the console or a dataset node, I can run:

```
>>> print(aktueller_tag)
Column<b'current_date()'>
```

Since this is a column, I can add a new column to an existing dataset.

```
df = df.withColumn("today", aktueller_tag)
```

Here is an end to end example with the notional flight data in Foundry:

[image]

This is an example in the console:

```
>>> flight.withColumn("today",aktueller_tag)
DataFrame[unique_flight_id: int, flight_id: string, aircraft_registration: string, departure_date: date, arrival_date: date, domestic_or_international: string, scheduled_departure_airport: string, scheduled_arrival_airport: string, today: date]


>>> flight.withColumn("today",aktueller_tag).select("today").show(1)
+----------+
|     today|
+----------+
|2022-03-30|
+----------+
```

Now if you wanted to write the filter, an easy way would be:

```
flight = flight.withColumn("today",aktueller_tag)
flight_today = flight.where(F.col("today")==F.col("departure_date"))
```

Where departure_date is the column you wanted to filter on. I hope this helps!